# FullCalendar background color of row of today in AgendaWeek view and AgendaDay view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Can someone help me for the code to change the background color only of the row of today in agendaWeek view and agendaDay view in Fullcalendar? Here is code of my calendar:

```
<style>
        body {
            padding-top: 70px;
            /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
        }
        #calendar {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        #calendar.agenda-week{
          background-color: #FF9900;
        }
</style>
//...
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            locale: "es",
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            views: {
                week: {
                columnFormat:'ddd D',
                },
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            minTime: "09:30:00",
            maxTime: "19:30:00",
            slotLabelFormat: "h(:mm)a",
            slotDuration: "00:30:00",
            slotLabelInterval: "00:30:00",
            businessHours:
            {
              start: '13:30',
              end:   '17:00',
              dow:  [1,2,3,4,5,6,0]
            },
            dayRender: function (date, cell) {

                var today = new Date();

                if (date.date() === today.getDate() && date.month() === today.getMonth()) 
                {
                   cell.css("background-color", "#C0C0C0");//gray for today in month view
                }                    

            },
            viewRender: function(view,element){
                $("#calendar").addClass('agenda');//this change background color to orange for all views
            },
            //...
        });
```

and here is the calendar at the moment

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope i understood you correctly.

With CSS you can do the following:

```
#calendar .fc-agendaWeek-view .fc-today,  #calendar .fc-agendaDay-view .fc-today {
  background: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really what i wanna do XD.